# What does the column in this statement means in java?

Tags: java

I would like to know what does this statement says. I have seen a lot of this type of statements but I do not know the meaning.

```
for (Rectangle rectangle: rectangles)
```

Comment: simple for loop Iterating the list , list of rectangles , every iteration , will have have object of a rectangle , in the variable rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here (Also know as for-each-loop):
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know anything related to Java is to refer Tutorials of Java by Oracle

[Java Tutorial - ForEach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's an *iterate over everything in rectangles idiom*; i.e. rectangle takes successively each possible reference in the rectangles collection, in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

This is [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)  in Java.

It is equivalent to :

```
for(int i =0; i < rectangles.size(); i++ )
    Rectangle rectangle = rectangles.get(i); // get() function to get the ith element of rectangles.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the **enhanced loop**. It iterates over all rectangles in a Collection. Functionally, its the same **traditiona** for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<rectangles.size(); i++) {
    Rectangle rectangle = rectangles.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Enhanced for loop**

```
for (iterable_type iterable_element : iterable) {

}
```

**Example**

```
 int [] numbers = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

  for(int x : numbers ){
     System.out.print( x );
     System.out.print(",");
  }
  System.out.print("\n");
  String [] names ={"James", "Larry", "Tom", "Lacy"};
  for( String name : names ) {
     System.out.print( name );
     System.out.print(",");
  }
```

**Output**

```
10,20,30,40,50,
James,Larry,Tom,Lacy,
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a shorthand for

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; ++i){
    Rectangle rectangle = rectangles.get(i);
    ...
```